# Capacitor: Unable to open asset URL:

Tags: android-studio, capacitor

On this image error look like this `E/Capacitor: Unable to open asset URL: https://example.com/assets/ha-logo-favicon.png`
[image]

this is `capacitor.config.json` not shown in the image:

```json
{
  "appId": "com.example.android",
  "appName": "example",
  "webDir": "dist",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "server": {
    "hostname": "example.com",
    "androidScheme": "https"
  }
}
```

```
D/Capacitor: Handling local request: https://example.com/assets/ha-logo-favicon.png
E/Capacitor: Unable to open asset URL: https://example.com/assets/ha-logo-favicon.png
E/Capacitor: Unable to open asset URL: https://example.com/assets/ha-logo-favicon.png
E/Capacitor: Unable to open asset URL: https://example.com/assets/ha-logo-favicon.png
D/Capacitor: Handling local request: https://example.com/assets/ha-logo.png
E/Capacitor: Unable to open asset URL: https://example.com/assets/ha-logo.png
D/Capacitor: Handling local request: https://example.com/assets/ha-logo-text.png
E/Capacitor: Unable to open asset URL: https://example.com/assets/ha-logo-text.png
E/Capacitor: Unable to open asset URL: https://example.com/assets/ha-logo.png
I/roadinc.androi: Thread[5,tid=12189,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xe18c7010,peer=0x12d8000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  "appId": "com.example.android",
  "appName": "example",
  "webDir": "dist",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "server": {
    "hostname": "example.com",
    "androidScheme": "https",
    "url": "https//example.com"
  }
}
```